# How do you store an IP Address (v4 or v6) as an int in any database using php?

Tags: sql, optimization, ip-address

I need to store IP address in the most compact way possible, searching is not a concern. This also needs to be compatible on Windows, Linux, and Mac using any DB (MySQL, SQLite, Postgres, etc).

Thanks to the [ip2long()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) and long2ip() functions in PHP I can convert a IP4 address to a small int field rather than a varchar(15) or whatever. The problem is that we are in a transition stage to IP6 which means that most of the existing best-practices are failing - including those functions which don't work with IP6. Further more, DB specific functions like INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() aren't options here.

So how do you store IP address as INT's (or any other compact format) in a way that will work on any system?

EDIT:
[The thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php) Wrang-wrang pointed mentions the use of inet_ntop() and inet_ptop() to pack and unpack either IP4 or IP6. The problem is that they only work on Linux/Mac with PHP +5.1 (which isn't a too big of a problem) and on windows with +5.3 (which is).

If that was not a problem are their replacements for the varbinary(16) field that was recommended in each database?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database). The poster settled on using two `BIGINT` fields to store an IPv6 address, but there are other suggestions there as well which you may want to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to choose a way of storing 128 bits:

> ::/96 — This is a 96-bit zero-value
>   prefix originally known as
>   IPv4-compatible addresses. This class
>   of addresses were used to represent
>   IPv4 addresses within an IPv6
>   transition technology. Such an IPv6
>   address has its first 96 bits set to
>   zero, while its last 32 bits are the
>   IPv4 address that is represented. The
>   Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF)
>   has deprecated the use of
>   IPv4-compatible addresses with
>   publication RFC 4291. The only
>   remaining use of this address format
>   is to represent an IPv4 address in a
>   table or database with fixed size
>   members that must also be able to
>   store an IPv6 address.

(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)

I think two BIGINT UNSIGNED would be a reasonable way to store them, but I guess you could use a binary (byte array).

This question appears to have been answered already at [Working with IPv6 Addresses in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php) and [How to store IPv6-compatible address in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [universal php library](https://github.com/akalongman/php-ip-tools): its `ip2long` and `long2ip` methods work with both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: Please do read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085).