# insert ip into mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, ip-address

I came accross this statement for inserting an IP into a mysql table.

```
INSERT INTO `best` VALUES (132+256*(172+256*(109+256*(115))
```

I would like to know why an IP is being inserted this way, and how to actually work out what IP is being inserted

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386930/how-do-you-store-an-ip-address-v4-or-v6-as-an-int-in-any-database-using-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385552/datatype-for-storing-ip-address-in-sql-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038950/what-is-be-the-most-appropriate-data-type-for-storing-an-ip-address-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Its prefer storing the IP address in decimal (integer) as it makes it easier to work with later.

But you can use MySQL commands to easily convert the data. For instance if you retrieved the IP you can use the [`inet_aton('$ip')`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) command to convert the insert the IP Address ($ip) into decimal and then add the data into the database. You can convert the Decimal Address back to octets by using [inet_ntoa](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa)

see this links:

http://www.countryipblocks.net/networking/ip-address-conversion-to-decimal-and-binary-equivalents/

http://www.webproworld.com/web-programming-discussion-forum/85464-storing-ip-location-mysql-database.html

Comment: Interesting. So is there no way to look at the string above and work out the IP?

Comment: •INET_NTOA(expr) 
Given a numeric network address in network byte order (4 or 8 byte), returns the dotted-quad representation of the address as a string. 
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(3520061480);
        -> '209.207.224.40'

Comment: The IP address from your example above is 115.109.172.132. To match the numbers is up to you ;-)

Comment: http://ipinfodb.com/ use this technique to store ip address in their ip to country. For the column type, they use `bigint(20)` in the latest database release.

Answer (score 0):

that's way used to reduce the space used to store ip.

with this way you will store IPs in int type field, that is smaller in space  than char type