# Store IP in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, ip

I have a php my admin database,

I don't know very much how to structure it but following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982701/best-way-to-store-ip-in-database) 
I Made a

`ip      int(11)       UNSIGNED`

value for the IP

I would like to store the IP of user, so that they can't access twice to my page.

I do the following query

```
$ip = inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$request = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ip`) VALUES (".$ip.")";
$result = $dbh->query($request);
```

but this give me an empty value. and nothing is added to the database

**EDIT :**

User table [image]

So full request is :

```
function getIPforBDD(){
    return inet_pton($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
}
$request = "INSERT INTO `users` (`ip`, `finish`, `lastPage`) VALUES (".getIPforBDD().", ".$GLOBALS["userHasFinish"].", questionnaire_initial.php)";
$result = $dbh->query($request);
```

Comment: Please show the full users table columns.

Comment: [`inet_pton()`](http://il1.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) returns a string, not an integer. If you use [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) instead, you will get an integer. That's better since MySQL is faster to compare integers than strings.

Answer (score 0):

After using inet_pton() function, data won't be in readable format. Just use varchar(16) datatype in your database for ip column and change first row of your code to:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Many people over the internet when I was searching for this answer say this is a bad idea and give other solution (but are only in mysql so doesn't work in my case)

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this?

```
$request = "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ('$ip')";
```