# Detecting an IPv6 address in PHP and storing it properly in MySQL. How?

Tags: php, ipv6

I read a few of the questions already asked, and i found this to be useful, although i have no tried it [Working with IPv6 Addresses in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php)

Still, say i have a 'bans' table in MySQL. How would i go about storing the IPv6 address? The method must be universal, i.e the field must be able to contain either a ipv4 or ipv6 addr. This also must apply to my ip_addr field in my users table.

i would usually check `if(getip == $bans['ip']) { do something }`
But my getip function is for ipv4 afaik and i wonder if it will work.

The function i use is

```
function getip()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
    if(preg_match_all("#[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}#s", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'], $addresses))
    {
        foreach($addresses[0] as $key => $val)
        {
            if(!preg_match("#^(10|172\.16|192\.168)\.#", $val))
            {
                $ip = $val;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

if(!isset($ip))
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = '';
    }
}

$ip = preg_replace("#([^.0-9 ]*)#", "", $ip);
return $ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Still, say i have a 'bans' table in MySQL. How would i go about storing the IPv6 address?

You can store it in a simple column of VARCHAR(40).
Considering a sample IPv6 max is 40 byte:

```
2001:0DB8:0000:0000:0000:0000:1428:57ab
```

That coulmn will be able to contain IPv4 too

Comment: You are forgetting that IPv6 addr can be stored in a shorter format. Example:
fe80:0000:0000:0000:0202:b3ff:fe1e:8329 could be fe80:0:0:0:202:b3ff:fe1e:8329. Which WILL differ from the record in the DB

Comment: @dikidera: why not store it in a canonic way and compare to canonic one?

Comment: @dikidera: that's right. at this point before stroign them in mysql just replace :0: with :0000: and you are good.

Comment: On the wiki it says, that the short version can also become shorter i.e fe80:0:0:0:202:b3ff:fe1e:8329 can become fe80::202:b3ff:fe1e:8329 so this wont work either. I also need some working functions as this is a first for me.

Comment: @diki: that's not hard -.- replace :: with :0000:

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not going to be zeroes all the time.

Comment: @diki: :: means :0000: all the time

Comment: @yes123: No, it doesn’t. It means “a string of zeroes having the required length”. `::1` (loopback) does _not_ mean `:0000:1`, it means `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001`, while `2001:db8::1428:57ab` means `2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:1428:57ab`.

Answer (score 9):

I was searching for the best data type in mysql to use for storing an ipv6 address recently.   I have found no good reason to use a VARCHAR(), only good reasons **NOT** to.

I did some performance testing with the BINARY(16), two BIGINT UNSIGNED, and DECIMAL data types.

I've created the following tables, populated with 2,000,000 random ip address from 100 random networks.

```
CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_binary (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    addr BINARY(16) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_twobigints (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    haddr BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    laddr BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE uidx (haddr, laddr)
);

CREATE TABLE ipv6_address_decimal (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    addr DECIMAL(39,0) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Then I SELECT all ip addresses for each network and record the response time.  Average response time on the twobigints table is about 1 second while on the binary table it is about one-hundredth of a second.

Here are the queries.

> Note:
>
> X_[HIGH/LOW] is the most/least significant 64-bits of X
>
> when NETMASK_LOW is 0 the AND condition is omitted as it always yields true.  doesn't affect performance very much.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_twobigints
WHERE haddr & NETMASK_HIGH = NETWORK_HIGH
AND laddr & NETMASK_LOW = NETWORK_LOW

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_binary
WHERE addr >= NETWORK
AND addr <= BROADCAST

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ipv6_address_decimal
WHERE addr >= NETWORK
AND addr <= BROADCAST
```

Average response times:

[image: Average response times]

```
BINARY_InnoDB  0.0119529819489
BINARY_MyISAM  0.0139244818687
DECIMAL_InnoDB 0.017379629612
DECIMAL_MyISAM 0.0179929423332
BIGINT_InnoDB  0.782350552082
BIGINT_MyISAM  1.07809265852
```