# IPV6 notation of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, ipv6

I have many projects with functionalities relying on IP addresses provided by `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]`, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`, and `$_SERVER['CLIENT_IP']`.

IPV4 addresses are easy to match since we always receive them in the same format: 4 integers without the leading 0s, separated by a dot `.`.

Whereas IPV6 addresses can be compressed. Ex: FF01:0:0:0:0:0:0:101 -> FF01::101

I've been researching this issue but haven't found anything relevant, so I'm asking for your experience. Is `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR]` using a standard? Is it safe to assume that it will always be received as compressed or uncompressed?

Or should I compress all my IPV6 string before I try to try test them?

**Note:**

Ideally I would like to handle IPV6 addresses as strings rather than binary structure, to improve readability in Databases / Source code and allow easier IP range matching.

Comment: I haven't worked with IPv6 but I have the impression that you should `inet_pton()` any address you want to manipulate.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thank you for the comment, I will definitely look into this function. But I would like to keep the string notation if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [`inet_pton()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) first, and then convert it back to a string with [`inet_ntop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php) you should have a consistent string representation. I wouldn't rely on the input to be consistent...

Comment: I tested it and it seems to give a consistent result. This might be exactly what I'm looking for. I'm going to test it in a real life project to see if it could work.

Comment: I've tested, it works perfectly. And it's simple enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Sander [inet_pton()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) and [inet_ntop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php)...  can you put these links in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The [CGI spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) is clear that any RFC compliant IPv6 address is valid:

```
4.1.8.  REMOTE_ADDR

   The REMOTE_ADDR variable MUST be set to the network address of the
   client sending the request to the server.

      REMOTE_ADDR  = hostnumber
      hostnumber   = ipv4-address | ipv6-address
      ipv4-address = 1*3digit "." 1*3digit "." 1*3digit "." 1*3digit
      ipv6-address = hexpart [ ":" ipv4-address ]
      hexpart      = hexseq | ( [ hexseq ] "::" [ hexseq ] )
      hexseq       = 1*4hex *( ":" 1*4hex )

  The format of an IPv6 address is described in RFC 3513 [15].
```

A sane programmer validates all inputs. Therefore you should treat any environment variable as tainted input and validate/transform. Headers provided by a client, such as X-Forward-For et al should ALWAYS be treated with suspicion.

So what about expanding IPv6 addresses?

This question has [been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php) and [there are several solutions](http://www.soucy.org/project/inet6/) including [a PEAR one](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.networking.net-ipv6.uncompress.php)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will of course first validate it is a valid IP. Actually I'm using the functions provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php already to store IPV4 and IPV6 in a database. The PEAR solution seems like a good one, I will certainly give it a try.

Comment: even given that Pear function, trying to do range matches on an IPv6 in string format (even fully expanded) will be very difficult, particularly if the range doesn't fall on a nybble boundary (i.e. a /62)

Comment: @Alnitak Good point. My IP ranges can be reduced to nibble boundary, so a simple `strpos` should do the trick, assuming I have consistent input.

Answer (score 1):

The *recommended* format for IPv6 address is in [RFC 5952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952).

However you cannot rely on all addresses being in that format, and the string format is particularly lousy for range comparisons.  Reading the RFC will give you some idea as to just how many ways it's possible to legally represent the same IPv6 address.

You really should parse the address (using `inet_pton` as mentioned elsewhere) and perform your range comparisons on the resulting 128 bit field.

More often than not you'll only care about the 64 most significant bits, which fits nicely into a `long` on most architectures.