# Quick way of expanding IPv6 Addresses with PHP

Tags: php, ip-address, ipv6

I am working on a project where I needed to expand IPv6 addresses. That is, given the input `2600:fc00:b0a3::34` I need to get `2600:fc00:b0a3:0000:0000:0000:0000:0034`.

I found one piece of code that required the GMP extension, which I can't install. How can I fully expand an IPv6 address in PHP?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The following is a two liner, where `$ip` is a condensed IPv6 address. Returns expanded `$ip`.

**Example**:

```
$ip = "fe80:01::af0";
echo expand($ip); // fe80:0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0af0
```

**Function**:

```
function expand($ip){
    $hex = unpack("H*hex", inet_pton($ip));         
    $ip = substr(preg_replace("/([A-f0-9]{4})/", "$1:", $hex['hex']), 0, -1);

    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of `$ip`, like `echo expand($ip);` ?

Comment: Great ! Much interesting with an example :)

Comment: In all my years as a PHP developer, this is the best solution to functionality missing from the PHP core that I have ever seen (as are your dtr_pton / dtr_ntop functions). Beautifully simple and elegant.

Comment: Thank you, very elegant solution. I would suggest to write the second line as `return implode(':', str_split($hex['hex'], 4));`. Improves readability, avoid having to sanitise the extra colon with `substr` and avoid unecesssary use of regexp.

Answer (score 4):

With the help from Mike Mackintosh and Yann Milin I came up with this function:

```php
function expandIPv6(string $ip): string
{
    $hex = bin2hex(inet_pton($ip));
    return implode(':', str_split($hex, 4));
}
```

Below a more universal function witch will also extract IPv4 from an IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses:

```php
function expandIPv6(string $ip): string
{
    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4)) {
        return $ip;
    }

    if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6)) {
        $hex = bin2hex(inet_pton($ip));

        return str_starts_with($hex, '00000000000000000000ffff')
            // IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses
            ? long2ip(hexdec(substr($hex, -8)))
            : implode(':', str_split($hex, 4));
    }

    return '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks miken32 for making the code stricter!