# Getting customer IP insert into Database

Tags: php, mysql

Ive been trying to get the registered members ip to insert into the databse, 
my current code is as follows:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

```
if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email,password,ip) VALUES('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "', '$ip')")) {
        $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";
    } else {
        $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
    }
```

When it inserts into the database, it inputs a completely different string.
[Database fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfLUo.png)

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3L4j.png)

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: It looks like maybe your database field is of an integer type, it won't accept a string.

Comment: you haven't said what your IP address field is or what your data looks like but I am guessing that it's the numerical representation of the IP address that's being stored

Comment: Adding database structure now

Comment: `int(255)`, really? make that `varchar(255)`, which is "one" way.

Comment: I just assumed it would be an int, as it is numbers? My bad for trying.

Comment: if it's just integers, then see the duplicate it was closed with.

Comment: Well, the IP it is inserting into the database, isn't even my IP?! The hell?

Comment: The fact, it *is* an int aside, but where did you seen integers with *dots*?

Comment: then, that's a whole different ballgame, echo it out, what does it show?

Comment: @tedbaker, seems you need to go back to programming basics.  Not trying to be rude or anything, just blunt.  You should know the basics of what an integer, float, boolean, and string are before programming.

Comment: Its inserting the IP in the database now, but it is inserting not my IP. I have just double checked this.
141.xxx.xxx.171, my ip is is actually: 2.xxx.xxx.132

Comment: @tedbaker are you on a proxy? See this Q&A also http://stackoverflow.com/q/444966/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/12970821/1415724 could be relevant.

Comment: It was getting the address off from my cloudflare for some strange reason, I have changed the $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to <Br>if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

Comment: .......and did that ^ solve it?

Comment: ..indeed it has

Comment: @tedbaker Great. Well, in all fairness to the question and the real problem, I reopened it but marked it as another duplicate. I couldn't close it in one go, since I already voted earlier.