# Which MySQL datatype to use for an IP address?

Tags: php, mysql, types, ip-address

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store an IP in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108918/how-to-store-an-ip-in-mysql)

I want to get the IP address from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and some other `$_SERVER` variables, which datatype is the right one for this?

Is it `VARCHAR(n)`?

Comment: See this [discussion](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,49094,49094#msg-49094)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate question, since the other question is specifically a performance-related question for storing a very large number of ip addresses.  The answer to that question might not be relevant to someone who is not interested in maximizing space usage or performance.

Comment: @User I've asked this question about one and a half years ago ;) But thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: Even though this question is a _possible_ duplicate. Here I have found better answers. Those who marked it as duplicate, made me waste my time :-P

Comment: Can anyone please unmark this as a duplicate. The real answer is in this question.

Comment: It feels like every third SO answer I search for, the top result is "[DUPLICATE]".  I think some people just like closing questions, and whether it's correct or not isn't really important.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Since IPv4 addresses are 4 byte long, you could use an [`INT` (`UNSIGNED`)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-types.html) that has exactly 4 bytes:

```
`ipv4` INT UNSIGNED
```

And [`INET_ATON`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) to convert them:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`ipv4`) VALUES (INET_ATON("127.0.0.1"));
SELECT INET_NTOA(`ipv4`) FROM `table`;
```

For IPv6 addresses you could use a [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html) instead:

```
`ipv6` BINARY(16)
```

And use [PHP’s `inet_pton`](http://php.net/inet_pton) and [`inet_ntop`](http://php.net/inet_ntop) for conversion:

```
'INSERT INTO `table` (`ipv6`) VALUES ("'.mysqli_real_escape_string(inet_pton('2001:4860:a005::68')).'")'
'SELECT `ipv6` FROM `table`'
$ipv6 = inet_pton($row['ipv6']);
```

Comment: Syntax for 5.1 is INT UNSIGNED, not UNSIGNED INT

Comment: With the suggested method - How to find addresses with matching subnet?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber [Check if IP is in subnet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002060/53114)

Comment: What if it could be either?

Comment: New Update: INET6_ATON() For IPV6 INET6_NTOA()

Comment: When storing as binary format - IPv6 addresses using INET6_NTOA() and INET6_ATON() - use HEX() and UNHEX() for readability. And if you are fetching something based on IP address, make sure you use index on this column and query actually uses that index while execution - check here http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/08/how-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 57):

You have two possibilities (for an IPv4 address) :

- a **`varchar(15)`**, if your want to store the IP address as a string

  - `192.128.0.15` for instance
- an **`integer`** (4 bytes), if you convert the IP address to an integer

  - `3229614095` for the IP I used before

The second solution will require less space in the database, and is probably a better choice, even if it implies a bit of manipulations when storing and retrieving the data *(converting it from/to a string)*.

About those manipulations, see the [`ip2long()`](https://www.php.net/ip2long) and [`long2ip()`](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.long2ip.php) functions, on the PHP-side, or [`inet_aton()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`inet_ntoa()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) on the MySQL-side.

Comment: But I've heard that it also can be an IPv6 address in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].
And how could I convert something like xxx.xx.xx.xxx into an integer (4 bytes) like you said?

Comment: For an IPv6 address, you'll need more than 4 bytes -- https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/IPv6 says it uses 128 bits, so 16 bytes ;; in PHP, see http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php

Comment: Which datatype would be correct for 16 bytes?

Comment: Considering that none of the integer datatype is more than 8 bytes (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html ) ? I would say you'll have to fallback to some kind of char-based type.

Comment: @ComFreek or somelse who stumble upon this 192*256*256*256 + 128*256*256 + 15 = 3229614095

Comment: `BINARY(128)` can be used for storing ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score 5):

For IPv4 addresses, you can use VARCHAR to store them as strings, but also look into storing them as long integesrs `INT(11) UNSIGNED`.  You can use MySQL's `INET_ATON()`  function to convert them to integer representation.  The benefit of this is it allows you to do easy comparisons on them, like `BETWEEN` queries

[INET_ATON() MySQL function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton)