# Check if two IPv6 addresses in same subnet using MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, ipv6, ipv4

I'm looking for a select statement that will check if 2 IP addresses are in the same subnet, based on how many bits in the host portion of the mask.  I found [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001933/check-if-ip-is-in-subnet) and answer, but it only works for IPv4 addresses.

My MySQL statement for IPv4 is as follows where 3 is the number of bit in the host portion of the mask (21 bit network):

```
SELECT FROM table WHERE ((-1 << 3) & INET_ATON(IPADDRESS1) = (-1 << 3) & INET_ATON(IPADDRESS2))
```

Can anyone create an IPv6 equivalent?  (It's beyond my even attempting).  I realize there is a INET6_ATON but the -1 I use to create the 1's mask above won't work (due to length), along with probably other reasons.

If it helps, we can assume that the IPv6 address is in RFC 5952 format, or the full 8 colon separated numbers.

Comment: i'll ping Rick on his related answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104844)

Comment: The link Drew gave may be more relevant than my Answer below.  Let me know whether you need further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of problems here.  Most of the answers are [*here*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ip-range-table-performance/) and in the [*reference implementation for IPv6*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipv6.sql)

Before you spit at me for having a link-only answer, here are some hints of what is going on.

- The links refer to an efficient way to handle non-overlapping ranges, such as IP addresses.  However, part of the solution is to be able to add/subtract 1 from a 128-bit value.  See the Functions `IpIncr` and `IpDecr`.
- For producing a mask, I would recommend converting to 32-character hex, then playing with substrings.  See `CONCAT, LEFT, RIGHT, REPEAT`, etc.  Once you have done that, string comparisons should easily handle checking for "in network".

The code will be simpler in MySQL 8.0 because `BLOBs` can be treated as really long bit strings; previously bit stuff was limited to `BIGINT`, which is not big enough for IPv6.

Comment: I read your linked answer...and can't turn that into a solution (I'm not that skilled yet).  I can create a table with binary(16) col of all possible netmasks (128).  But then how do I turn your WHERE statement into a select that checks 2 IP addresses for on the same subnet of X bits?

Comment: Yeah, the table look sounds practical for generating the mask.  (`SELECT @mask := mask FROM Masks WHERE bits=...`)  The link Drew gave shows how to test against it (using `@mask`).  Make `mask` `BINARY(32)`.

Comment: Hoping for something simpler...would this work (assuming I make a 128 '1' string):  INET6_ATON(IPADD1) & (INET6_ATON("1111..11") << 3) =  INET6_ATON(IPADD2) & (INET6_ATON("1111..11") << 3)

Comment: Stop thinking in "left shift"; it is not part of the solution.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to work in "binary" (b'10101010', etc).  I would try to work in hex.  A mask with start with some number of `F`, have one middle character (`8/C/E`), then the rest is a string of `0`.

Comment: And use `HEX()` and `UNHEX()` to convert between `BINARY(16)` and the hex version in `BINARY(32)`.

Comment: Still wrapping head around this.  Why is left shift not appropriate?  I thought that would be simplest way to make a mask.  Or are you saying MySQL can't shift a Binary(16)?  As I'm creating the SELECT from PHP, I can easily construct a string with the right number of 1 bits...if that's simpler (avoid mask table).  If Binary(16) can shift left, can it logical and?

Comment: Left shift is very complicated when dealing with 128 bits in MySQL.  It cannot shift `BINARY(16)` (until version 8.0).

Comment: Ditto for logical AND, etc.  Nothing bigger than 64 bits.  (Or perhaps the limit is 63 bits.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for when the addresses are stored as strings.

A similar problem is to find all addresses in the database that belonged to a specific subnet, which is rather similar to the problem posted here, to check whether two addresses are in the same subnet.

It is a little tricky, especially for IPv6.  In IPv6 there can optionally be compressed segments, like 1::1 which is equivalent to 1:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, which is the main reason it is tricky.

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/#_Toc456708509) will produce mysql SQL to search for addresses in a given subnet.  The link describes this problem in more detail.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

The basic algorithm is to take the network section of the subnet address, then take each variant of that section (for example the two strings above are variants of the full address 1::1), then count the number of segment separators, then do a mysql substring on the address being matched, but also count the total separators in the address being matched.

Here is sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IPAddressStringException {
    System.out.println(getSearchSQL("columnX", "1.2.3.4/16"));
    System.out.println(getSearchSQL("columnX", "1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8/64"));
    System.out.println(getSearchSQL("columnX", "1::8/64"));
}

static String getSearchSQL(String expression, String ipAddressStr) throws IPAddressStringException {
    IPAddressString ipAddressString = new IPAddressString(ipAddressStr);
    IPAddress ipAddress = ipAddressString.toAddress();
    IPAddressSection networkPrefix = ipAddress.getNetworkSection(ipAddress.getNetworkPrefixLength(), false);
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("Select rows from table where ");
    networkPrefix.getStartsWithSQLClause(sql, expression);
    return sql.toString();
}
```

Ouptut:

```
Select rows from table where (substring_index(columnX,'.',2) = '1.2')
Select rows from table where (substring_index(columnX,':',4) = '1:2:3:4')
Select rows from table where ((substring_index(columnX,':',4) = '1:0:0:0') OR ((substring_index(columnX,':',2) = '1:') AND (LENGTH (columnX) - LENGTH(REPLACE(columnX, ':', '')) <= 5)))
```

Comment: I could do that outside MySQL too (using PHP) but my goal was to do this in MySQL exclusively (otherwise search load will be high)