# IP address wrong on database insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, input, ip

I'm having a problem writting an IP to the database. 
If I print $ip after `$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`, I obtain 54.231.128.128. But if I insert ip to database, it inserts 203223. Here is my code.

```
<?php include "db.php";
session_start();
$toemail=$_POST["toemail"];
$report=$_POST["report"];
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$fromemail=$_SESSION['nahid'];
$date=(time());
$tatus="Active";

if(!$_POST['submit'])   {
    echo "Please fill out the form";

    }   else    {

    // $query_auto = "INSERT INTO form (date, time) VALUE ('DATE: Auto CURDATE()', CURDATE() )";


mysql_query("INSERT INTO report(`id`, `from`, `msg`, `to`, `date`, `ip`, `status`) 
            VALUES(NULL,'$fromemail','$report','$toemail','$date', '$ip', '$tatus')") or die(mysql_error());
    header('Location: report_congratulations.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: what type is the IP column in your database?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: ip column type should be varchar, or you could use php function `ip2long` to convert ip to number, and when retrieving use `long2ip` to convert back to ip

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133580/which-mysql-datatype-for-an-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

> REFERENCE [INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [INET_NTOA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO report(`id`, `from`, `msg`, `to`, `date`, (INET_ATON('$ip')), `status`) 
        VALUES(NULL,'$fromemail','$report','$toemail','$date', '$ip', '$tatus')") or      die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Sorry It was mistake. Extremely sorry.

Comment: @SMNahidurRahman can you upvote and accept my answer if it is useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. My Database IP column was integer. But now I converted varchar and problem has solved.