# why inet_pton works but inet_ntop fails?

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Hello I want to save ip_addresses into my mysql database. It should work for ipv4 and ipv6. I found the solution to use inet_pton from php.
However 90% of the entries are fine but 10% fails to convert with inet_nton back to ipv6 or ipv4 (not sure which one)

my database looks like so

> ip    - varchar(30) - latin1_bin

I just do

```
$ip_pton = inet_pton($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

if I try to convert back I just use **inet_ntop**. Like above I said maybe from 100 entries I get just few warnings

> Warning: inet_ntop(): Invalid in_addr value

Example converted ip is this "`E" It cannot be converted back. I get the error above.

I did I maybe use wrong data types in mysql?

Comment: Check this. Possible Answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133580/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-an-ip-address/5133610#5133610

Comment: @chris85 but I don't save real ipv4 & ipv6. I convert it first. You see the quoted example above? This cannot be over 30 chars :p. Maybe I just use full length and do something like varchar(50) and I put ipv6 and ipv4 there.

Comment: Oh, yup, you are right. Can you post a valid an example and an erring example?