# IP addresses get stored as 0 when converting with PHP ip2long function

Tags: php, mysql, ip, ip-address

The newsletter_ip field in MySQL is set as an UNSIGNED INT (10). I've also tried INET_ATON to format the data, but my results always look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNGnL.png).

Here is part of my processing code:

```
//Retrieve data from user and create variables

$ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ip = ip2long($ip_orig);

//Place into database

$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', '".$ip."', '".$date."', '".$time."')";
```

I've also tried this snippet prior to the ip2long formatting, to no avail:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
    $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}else{
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try using a varchar(15) instead of a string for an IP address.

Comment: You [cannot trust X-Forwarded-For](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003233/238978)!

Comment: I believe you may be sending a value that is out of range. Either use BIGINT or VARCHAR to store as a string. I would also consider IPv6 addresses.

Comment: IP is min. of 15 chars (longer for IPv6).

Comment: Neither `varchar(15)` nor `unsigned int(10)` are going to help you with IPv6 addresses. Do you have the option of using a [database that can store IP addresses natively](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-net-types.html)?

Comment: This question addresses the problem as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108918/how-to-store-an-ip-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

for the root cause of your problem, ip2long gives a **signed** int as the PHP manual states:

Note:

Because PHP's integer type is signed, and many IP addresses will result in negative integers on 32-bit architectures, you need to use the "%u" formatter of sprintf() or printf() to get the string representation of the unsigned IP address.

And you store it as an **unsigned int**, thats the reason why you see ony zeros. For a standard and clean solution handling IPv6 others have already given the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since an IP address has several dots in it, or it may be a [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address, I would suggest you set the newsletter_ip field as a VARCHAR

Right now your IP addresses may be showing up as 0 because they are not actually integers.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the long as a string, not as a long.

You are also better off making the conversion in MySQL itself:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES ('".$email."', INET_ATON('".$ip."'), '".$date."', '".$time."')";
```

To retreive the IP address, do:

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(newsletter_ip) as newsletter_ip FROM newsletter;
```

`INET_ATON`  = Address to number

`INET_NTOA` = Number to Address

Answer (score 0):

Does printing out the ip before storing give you the correct value? If not, check if a proxy exists which removes this information from the request or renames it.

Anyways, there is no gain in storing the ip as long. There should not be a notable loss in performance if you use a string for this field which is much more straight forward and easier to handle. And while you're at it, leave enough space for IPv6 ;-)

Comment: Proxies can't remove `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`. It's server side. Apache knows all.

Comment: If it is a local proxy in front of the web server on the same machine, it would always set 127.0.0.1, for example.

Comment: you'd know about this proxy running on the same machine, but anyway, 127.0.0.1 is still an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting MySQL translate the IP using [**INET_ATON**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) on the server side ?

```
//Retrieve data from user and create variables

$ip_orig = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//Place into database

$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter(newsletter_email, newsletter_ip, newsletter_date, newsletter_time) VALUES('".$email."', INET_ATON('".$ip."'), '".$date."', '".$time."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use varchar(15) as min... varchar(45) to support newer IPv6 addresses, also here is my IP function:

```
function ip()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```