# Storing IP address in database as integer

Tags: php, mysql

i'm storing ip adress in database as integer, with [ip2long()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php), column type is unsigned int, but for some ip in database it saves as 0, i tested and some ip for ip2long function returns negative integer and when i insert it in database it saves as 0. i googled and everyone says that column must be unsigned int.

for example: `ip2long("212.36.25.15");` will return `-735831793` and in database it will be saved as `0`

Comment: You'll need to change the type of your database column from 'integer' to 'unsigned int'

Comment: column is unsigned int, but for some ips it saves as 0.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210713/ip-addresses-get-stored-as-0-when-converting-with-php-ip2long-function This may be of use to you

Comment: Why are you converting them like this? A`VARCHAR` column is a better plan since it can store IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Your numerical solution is IPv4 only, setting yourself up for failure later. An IPv4 address is an unsigned 32-bit value, but unless you're storing billions of them, use strings. It's safer and more flexible.

Comment: Postgres has special Network Address Types: cidr and inet since 9.1. They are great.

Answer (score 4):

Insert the ip address using INET_ATON.

eg: INET_ATON('127.0.0.1');

get back the ip address using INET_NTOA

eg: SELECT INET_NTOA('2130706433');

Comment: yes, i tested with mysql functions and it is working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the MySQL function INET_ATON instead.

Comment: yes, i tested with mysql functions and it is working.