# Add binary(16) Ip value to MySql database

Tags: mysql, binary

I am trying to populate a MySQL database field with a binary(16) value of an IP address and I'm getting:

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'IP' at row 1

The binary value I am trying to insert is

> 00000000000000000000ffff5bd25452

What am I doing wrong?

[MySql table schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGAZh.jpg)

Comment: The "binary" value you are trying to insert is actually a hexadecimal value, consisting of at least `12x4 = 48` bits.  Is your binary column wide enough to store this value?  Show us your table schema please.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin and this is one of the values already inserted in the previous fields. I have added a picture with the MySQL schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently you're losing data for using BINARY(16). To insert you need to unhex the value, for example:

```
INSERT INTO <your-table> (IP) VALUES(UNHEX("00000000000000000000ffff5bd25452"));
```

To get it back you'll be required to use HEX, to have the original form back:

```
SELECT HEX(IP) FROM <your-table>;
```

---

**Edit 1**: in apropos of your comment

> how can I insert an IP string such as 107.180.58.16

As IPv4 addresses are 4 byte long, same as an `INT (UNSIGNED)`:

Use `INET_ATON` to convert it to `INT`, and `INET_NTOA` to convert it back to IPv4 - for example:

```
INSERT INTO <your-table> (IP) VALUES (INET_ATON("107.180.58.16"));
SELECT INET_NTOA(IP) FROM <your-table>;
```

And, for IPv6 addresses i.e. 128 bits you can use 16 bytes binary field, `BINARY(16)` or `VARBINARY(16)`.

---

- [How to store an IP in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108918/how-to-store-an-ip-in-mysql)

Comment: The correct SQL syntax should be `INSERT INTO <your-table> (IP) VALUES(UNHEX("00000000000000000000ffff5bd25452"));` but I still failed to understant how can I insert an IP string such as `107.180.58.16` for example