# mySQL Length for a IPv4 Address (INT Field Type)

Tags: php, mysql

To store IPv4 Addresses in my Sql, I am using a INT field type.

Since the length is mandatory, what is the correct field length then ?

Also, I use PHP ip2long to store visitor's IP Address; so to prevent any errors in future, should I consider IPv6 instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to store IPv4 has already been answered on StackOverflow ([Storing IP address in MySQL database (IPv4 AND IPv6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589887/storing-ip-address-in-mysql-database-ipv4-and-ipv6)), so I'm only going to answer the rest of your questions.

- The length of ints is only relevant if you use zerofill: it will pad with zeros until it's your specified length wide. It will not cut anything off, either. Ints are 4 bytes, so they can store anything between -(2^31) and 2^31-1, regarldess of your length specifier.
- IPv4 and IPv6 are not completely interchangable; many of your users will still connect using IPv4 only, or IPv6 only; there is no 'conversion'. Try and make your implementation such that both can be stored. See the link provided.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you consider IPv6 compatibility, you can use in PHP [inet_pton](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) and inet_ntop to pack those values. For storing the value in MySQL, you should use VARBINARY(16).

A pure MySQL solution as of **MySQL 5.6.3 or newer** can use [INET6_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) and INET6_NTOA for converting the values. Both functions work for IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

VARCHAR(15).  You probably don't need ip2long.  It depends how you're going to use it when you take it back out of the database, but you're probably better off converting it after you retrieve it from the database than before. (ip2long is used to calculate ip ranges or use conditionals on ip addresses)