# printf ipv6 address using struct in6_addr and ipv4 address using u_int32_t

Tags: c, printf, ipv6, ipv4

I want to `printf` the values of ipv6 address whose type is  `struct in6_addr`  and ipv4 address whose type is `u_int32_t` to console.

I have tried type casting but it yields error

```
error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected
printf("---------------- ipv4= %zu ipv6 = %zu ",(size_t)ipv4, (size_t)ipv6);
```

I have also tried `%s ,%lu` and many other ways after going through the old question in stack overflow and other places .

If anyone has a solution to it I shall be greatly thankful .

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727421/expand-an-ipv6-address-so-i-can-print-it-to-stdout

Answer (score 6):

`in6_addr` is a struct which contains a union, you can't just cast it to size_t and hope it will work. You should use `inet_ntop` to convert it to human-readable form. See [http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntopman.html](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet%5fntopman.html) for more info.

Comment: right from the moment i heard about inet_ntop I have been tryin to pass my ipv6 address into this function and obtain a string that can be used to process furthur. However I can find a suitable implementation . Do you have c code that achieves this ?