# How to see binary representation of variable

Tags: php

Is there any possibility to see binary representation of variable?

Comment: what exactly do you want to see? number in base2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like so:

```
echo decbin(3); // 11
```

Answer (score 8):

Another solution:

```
function d2b($dec, $n = 16) {
    return str_pad(decbin($dec), $n, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Example:

```
// example:
echo d2b(E_ALL);
echo d2b(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
echo d2b(0xAA55);
echo d2b(5);

Output:
0111011111111111
0111111111111111
1010101001010101
0000000000000101
```

Comment: `$n = PHP_INT_SIZE * 8;`

Answer (score 5):

`decbin(your_int)` will return a string in binary numbers representing the same value as `your_int`, assuming that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
/**
 *    Returns an ASCII string containing
 *    the binary representation of the input data .
**/
function str2bin($str, $mode=0) {
    $out = false;
    for($a=0; $a < strlen($str); $a++) {
        $dec = ord(substr($str,$a,1));
        $bin = '';
        for($i=7; $i>=0; $i--) {
            if ( $dec >= pow(2, $i) ) {
                $bin .= "1";
                $dec -= pow(2, $i);
            } else {
                $bin .= "0";
            }
        }
        /* Default-mode */
        if ( $mode == 0 ) $out .= $bin;
        /* Human-mode (easy to read) */
        if ( $mode == 1 ) $out .= $bin . " ";
        /* Array-mode (easy to use) */
        if ( $mode == 2 ) $out[$a] = $bin;
    }
    return $out;
}
?>
```

Copied from: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: it'd be easier to replace the inner loop with decbin(), or at least use bit shifting rather than exponential functions.

Comment: yes I also noticed it. It's not mine code I just copied from the php site.

Answer (score 3):

Or you may use base_convert function to convert symbol codes to binary, here's a modified function:

```
function str2bin($str) 
{
    $out=false; 
    for($a=0; $a < strlen($str); $a++)
    {
        $dec = ord(substr($str,$a,1)); //determine symbol ASCII-code
        $bin = sprintf('%08d', base_convert($dec, 10, 2)); //convert to binary representation and add leading zeros
        $out .= $bin;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

It is useful to convert inet_pton() result to compare ipv6 addresses in binary format (since you cannot really convert a 128-bit ipv6 address to integer, which is 32- or 64-bit in php).
You can find more on ipv6 and php [here (working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444966/working-with-ipv6-addresses-in-php) and [here (how-to-convert-ipv6-from-binary-for-storage-in-mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120371/how-to-convert-ipv6-from-binary-for-storage-in-mysql).

Answer (score 2):

```
$a = 42;
for($i = 8 * PHP_INT_SIZE - 1; $i >= 0; $i --) {
    echo ($a >> $i) & 1 ? '1' : '0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about: `<?php
$binary = (binary) $string;
$binary = b"binary string";
?>`

(from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php))

Comment: That doesn't show the string in binary representation, it only "converts" (or casts) a literal string into a binary string.