# inet_ntop not returning the correct value

Tags: mysql, binary, inet-ntop

I am at a loss here.  I have inserted an IP address into a MySql table using inet_pton in a binary(16) column and when I try and retrieve it using inet_ntop I get a weird result

it displays:  23a6::

It should display: 35.166.0.0

```
    $Results = $this->DB->GetResults( "SELECT * FROM {$this->Table} WHERE type = '{$this->BlockType['Network']}'" );



    foreach($Results->Results as $Range)
    {

       echo  inet_ntop($Range->RangeStart);
    }
```

The hex value in the database is 0x23a60000000000000000000000000000

It seems like it should be working.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How did you work out 0x23a60000000000000000000000000000 was 35.166.0.0? How was it inserted? Using MySQL it seems to be 0x353938303831353336 looking at [inet_aton](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ea6028c579d65ca7b03b80d3a051a9c). You could use the inet_ntoa function like this example.

Comment: I used inet_pton to insert it into the database

Comment: You might need pack/unpack like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932682/php-unpacking-in-addr-to-a-string-representation-of-an-int)