# PHP Function hex2bin() doesn't return binary strings

Tags: php

The php manual says that hex2bin() returns a string with a binary representation.

I have this code:

```
$hex = hex2bin("6578616d706c65206865782064617461");
var_dump($hex);
```

The output is:

```
string 'example hex data' (length=16)
```

Pardon me if I'm wrong but I believe that the output isn't a binary string??
Did the manual made an error, or am I missing something?

-------------edit------------

Is `'example hex data'` a binary representation of data?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php: "Caution

This function does NOT convert a hexadecimal number to a binary number. This can be done using the base_convert() function.
"

Comment: what you want hex to binary conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hex2bin` turns hexadecimal numbers into raw bytes. These raw bytes output to the screen will be interpreted by your browser and/or CLI, which will turn it into text. `bin2hex` does *not* return a string like "01001000101" if that's what you expected; that'd be an *ASCII representation of a binary string*, not a binary string. See for example this if that's what you want: [How to see binary representation of variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5705267/476)

Answer (score 2):

From [php manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php):
"This function does NOT convert a hexadecimal number to a binary number. This can be done using the `base_convert()` function."

"Decodes a hexadecimally encoded (binary) string" and "Returns the binary representation of the given data"
(machine code ie. what's written to disk or processed by the computer hardware)

To answer your question:

Yes *`'example hex data'` **is** a (decoded) binary representation of (the given text) data*.
The hex (encoded) representation of the same data is `6578616d706c65206865782064617461`.
To display the binary (base 2) equivalent of the above hex (base 16) number, you'd `base_convert()` it (to get a string of 0s & 1s; the ASCII codes/representation)

The confusion seems to arise between the results of `hex2bin` and `base_convert()`.

As an example:

> Some data on disk can be displayed (on console) as 'A'
>  `bin2hex`
> would return this (encoded) as '41' (hex representation).
> `base_convert()` would return this (same) data as '01000001'
> `hex2bin` would then decode this '41' to the machine (ASCII)
> code equivalent 'A' (the binary representation, which may be written to disk as binary data)