# How should ip2long converted IP's be stored in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know enough about the function, or ip's, to determine how my column structure should be for storing this. Any suggestions?

Comment: IPv4 is a 4 byte address, so that fits perfectly into an unsigned INT. (That's what `long` in `ip2long` is.) IPv6 addresses won't fit in 4 bytes though =) You'll need 16 bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use an unsigned `INT` field for it.

Also see http://lists.mysql.com/cluster/2781 for a discussion about it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `INT` is fine when you're dealing with IPv4 addresses. However 128-bits long IPv6 can't be stored as `INT` or even `BIGINT`.

1. [How to store IPv6-compatible address in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database)
2. [How to convert IPv6 from binary for storage in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120371/how-to-convert-ipv6-from-binary-for-storage-in-mysql)
3. http://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=storing+ipv6+mysql&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8