# Cant store ip as int in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I am trying to store an ip after i have used the function `ip2long()`
but it won't INSERT anything when i use this function? if i change $ip = 10; it will store 10 as my ip in the database, but it won't store the number returned from the function.

I have tried to check if the returned value is a int with `is_int()` and it returns true.

The ip in the database is a int(39), so basically why won't it update my database?

PHP/SQL

```
$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$stmtt = $dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO rating_users (imgId, rating, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmtt->bind_param('iii', $imgValue, $voteValue, $ip);
$stmtt->execute();
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log if any errors are thrown?

Comment: Your answer is here => https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html being `unsigned INT` if it's not already that. What is the exact schema for it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842085/how-should-ip2long-converted-ips-be-stored-in-mysql

Comment: If your int field is signed you need to make it unsigned.

Comment: they come to ask, we answer... we stare and wait for answers on comments asking for clarification; and you are where, testing? having breakfast? gone to school? other? I swear, it's like pulling teeth; again.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Cool Off ... looks like temperature at your place is really high :)

Comment: Sorry i was making me a some food :) the problem was unsigned, i am very thankfull for the answer and help :)

Comment: @Rahul my eyes get tired faster now *lol* after all that "staring" for updates.

Comment: *"Sorry i was making me a some food"* - well, I wasn't far from the truth *lol!* *"having breakfast?"* - not bad huh? ;-)

Comment: lol i still wonder how it evolved this way tho xD but thanks for the great response and help :)