# Encrypting user's IP address before storing it

Tags: php, mysql, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I'm using [PHP](http://www.php.net/) and [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/), and I want to store users' IP addresses into the database for *comparison* purposes (e.g. allowing only one flag to a thread per IP). Would it be okay to do it the following way?

Retrieving it in PHP:

```
$ipAddress = md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
```

And then saving it into the database as a `VARCHAR(32)`.

If I had to make a more comprehensive use of the IPs this wouldn't be the proper way to do it I guess, but if it's only to make sure that the same IP didn't do something twice would be okay to use the [`md5`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) encryption to simplify things (unifying [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses into one)?

Comment: Nitpick comment, but md5 is a hash algorithm, not encryption. Encryption is different.

Comment: why encrypt? why reference IPS? they are un-predictable.

Comment: why encrypt? IPs aren't sensitive information.

Comment: There is absolutely no sense in whatever "encrypting" or "hashing" IPs.    
Just leave it as is. -1 for the pointless question

Comment: re downvotes: I think it's perfectly legitimate to store peer addresses in hashed form instead of plain, so that you can still enforce a usage policy (one "flag" whatever that is per address) without the posibility of associating the annotation back to a particular address.  I don't think MD5(peer address) is sufficient for all but a modest level of privacy, though.  perhaps sha1(affected resource + peer_address) would be better.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy exactly, I don't _need_ to know the actual IP address, I just want to make sure that a certain activity it's not repeated from the same IP. I'm glad some people actually read the question.

Comment: One thing to bear in mind is that legacy (or v4) IP addresses are fairly short, only 32 bits. As a result any hash you use will be trivially brute-forced back to the legacy IP address itself. It's fine if this is just a protection against casual observation by system admins or similar, but if you need real protection of the information you should just not store it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is fine, though your terminology is wrong: this is hashing, and hashing is not encryption.

You should also parse the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` and `Client-IP` headers unless you want to block everyone behind a proxy as if they were a single user (e.g. everyone at large companies, high schools, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yes, my terminology was wrong. I wasn't trying to emphasize on the `md5` hash algorithm or security but on "uniformize" (or normalizing) the IPs to make them easier to store

Comment: @YourCommonSense calm down, you might think that this is a pointless question, but it's not. It's something I need for a Web application and it's been already answered. What it's pointless is making comments like yours

Comment: @JohnDoe thank you for your comment, I got the matter. Please read my answer.

Comment: Trusting XFF and similar headers sent by outside servers is a terrible idea. It makes it really easy to spoof  your IP by just sending the header yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider converting the IP to a number.  A little quicker on the lookup because it's numeric data and you can use INET_ATON() and INET_NTOA() in your queries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton

```
mysql> SELECT INET_ATON('10.0.5.9');
        -> 167773449
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa

```
mysql> SELECT INET_NTOA(167773449);
        -> '10.0.5.9'
```

PHP to Convert to a number

```
$ipA = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$octets = split ("\.", $ipA);
$ipN = ($octets[3] + $octets[2] * 256 + $octets[1] * pow(256,2) + $octets[0] * pow(256,3);
```

Also, you might want to consider the IP Address you're using with this function:

```
/* Get Actual IP Address, in spite of proxy server */
function getRealIpAddr() {
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))   //check ip from share internet
    {   $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))   //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {   $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']; }
    else
    {   $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; }
    return $ip;
}
```

***RE***-Edit for IPv6:

Principles all still apply, but IPv6 Conversions already answered at [How to convert IPv6 from binary for storage in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120371/how-to-convert-ipv6-from-binary-for-storage-in-mysql)

Comment: No. You're not going to get the IPv6 address in dotted octets like that. Your code will simply not work.

Comment: fair enough - didn't respond to the comment correctly, so changed my answer to reflect link to IPv6 conversion, though I believe the answer to the original question still applies.