# What way should i create my download counter database? MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to create a download counter for my files. Here are my current table fields:

```
download_counter table
_______________________
ID - int(6) - AutoInc,
Product - varchar(128),
Version - varchar(128),
Date - date,
IP's - LONGTEXT
```

I am wondering if I should use my current table or should I use a more dynamic and flexible table, like this:

```
ID - int(11) - AutoInc,
Product - varchar(128),
Version - varchar(128),
Date - date,
IP - varchar(45)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is, I would definitely use a varchar instead of long text for an IP though

Comment: oh and it is BAD form to call a 'Date' field, 'Date', always use non system / reserved names, and something more descriptive, like `dld_date` or `requestDate`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would actually normalize your table properly:

```
download_counter {
   did,
   prodid,
   dldstamp,
   ip
}
```

and follow that up with your product table:

```
product_table {
   prodid,
   version,
   description,
   url,
   lastmodified,
   etc;
}
```

And you would just do inserts on your download_counter upon download request, referencing the **prodid**, from your product_table.

Simple enough and easy to normalize.  You would then manage your products/downloads in the separate table.

Answer (score 4):

I'd store a record per hit, but make sure you place indexes on any and all columns you'll be using to run `SELECT` queries on later.

Side note: If you want to store IP address in MySQL, you should take a look at the `INET_NTOA` and `INET_ATON` functions. They convert dotted notation IP address to 32 bit integers, allowing you to store the address in 4 bytes rather than 15 bytes. They must also be unsigned integers.

Comment: Until your site starts getting IPv6 traffic, in which case your IP's going to be every so slightly larger at 128bits instead of 32. Too bad MySQL doesn't have a native 128bit numeric type.

Comment: @Marc B Good point. It would be nice if MySQL had a native type (similiar to PostgreSQL's `inet`). I've read some stuff about using blobs or BIGINTs with IPv6. There's some discussion on the topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database/420688#420688

Comment: Yeah, two unsigned bigints is the only practical way to go if you want to use a native numeric type. At least the hex form of a v6 address isn't too long, so you're not stuck with char(128) if it was textified binary.