# Store IPV6 and IPV4 in MySql and also read it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php site. I want to store an last ip for each user. I want it to work for both IPV4 and IPV6 users. Any idea how?

Comment: Where is your problem? Connecting to a database in php, DB design, getting users IP,...?

Comment: Dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database Note the accepted answer, it explains how you would differentiate between IPv4 and IPv6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply convert them to a binary representation using [`inet_pton()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) and later back to a string using [`inet_ntop()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php).

Another solution would be storing the IP string without any transformations in the DB. A `VARCHAR(39)` field will do the job as the highest/longest IPv6 is `ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff`