# Best way to store an IPv6 in UNKNOWN DB?

Tags: database, store, ipv6, abstract

I know that this question has been asked quite a few times, but I could not find anywhere a final resolution; so here goes:

How do you store an IP (both IPv4 and IPv6) using best-practice, within a DB, without knowing the DB? This in case for DB abstraction purposes, such as PHP PDO.

On a minor note, I have PHP 5.2.17, as I needed PEAR on windows.

People have been suggesting to store it as a varbinary(16) and use mysql functions inet6_ntop and inet6_pton to pass IPs back and forth as strings; like [Extending MySQL 5 with IPv6 functions](http://labs.watchmouse.com/2009/10/extending-mysql-5-with-ipv6-functions/) is suggesting. In PHP, the functions inet_pton() and inet_ntop() can convert IPv4 and IPv6 back and forth to binary format as [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) in [this question is suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370876/store-ipv6-and-ipv4-in-mysql-and-also-read-it), but it is unclear how one would pass binary content into a SQL INSERT/UPDATE string (and these php functions are only provided with [php 5.3.0 on windows](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php), even though it is possible to reverse engineer these). I really like what [Jake](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574778/jake) did and [his results with regards to integer representations of IPs in DBs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242738/detecting-an-ipv6-address-in-php-and-storing-it-properly-in-mysql-how), and this may come in handy in some distant, unforeseen future, if I were to implement this into my DB, but then I'm unsure about DB cross-compatibilities for DB abstraction using PHP PDO. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049681/store-ipv6-in-database) seems to provide a close answer about storing binary values, but isn't unescaped binary injection into strings a potential hazard? Also, if you follow this route, how many DBs can convert a varbinary(16)/int(128bit) into a representational IP, if some developer wanted to do some quick lookups?

It seems to me that the most simple way is to insert the [ip string as-is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address) into a [varchar(45)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166132/maximum-length-of-the-textual-representation-of-an-ipv6-address). But how would those who want to follow the complicated route, in PHP (reverse-engineered [as djmaze(AT)dragonflycms(.)org](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php#59714) or as [MagicalTux at FF dot st](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php#52515) is suggesting) using the inet_ntop() and inet_pton() functions, store and retrieve an IPv6 as binary? Can someone give an example using PDO from `<?php $strIP = "2001:4860:b002::68"; ?>`, using an INSERT and then SELECT prepared statements?

As you can see, I've done my research, but the ultimate good-practice of this IPv6 isn't clear to me.

Comment: It really depends on what you need to be able to do with the IP address. If you just need to store and retrieve it, or compare it for an exact match with another IP address, a text string if fine. You can then do all of the transformations to and from binary format client-side (you'll need to to this once anyway upon insertion to guarantee the address is in canonical form). If you need to do database queries that involve prefix-length matching (e.g. Give me all the IP addresses covered by the prefix 2001:db8:1234::/46), text strings become a lot more inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like your research shows there are benefits and problems with storing IP addresses as strings in canonical form, binary strings or as integers. Maybe there is a middle ground to store IP addresses in a database.

How about storing them as strings, but expanded to the full maximum length. That way you can still compare them (==, >, <, etc) but they are also still readable and you don't need special input and output encoding of special characters.

An example of how you could do this:

```
function expand_ip_address($addr_str) {
  /* First convert to binary, which also does syntax checking */
  $addr_bin = @inet_pton($addr_str);
  if ($addr_bin === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  /* Then differentiate between IPv4 and IPv6 */
  if (strlen($addr_bin) == 4) {
    /* IPv4: print each byte as 3 digits and add dots between them */
    return implode('.', array_map(
      create_function('$byte', 'return sprintf("%03d", ord($byte));'),
      str_split($addr_bin)
    ));
  } else {
    /* IPv6: print as hex and add colons between each group of 4 hex digits */
    return implode(':', str_split(bin2hex($addr_bin), 4));
  }
}
```

And some examples:

```
/* Test IPv4 */
var_dump(expand_ip_address('192.0.2.55'));

/* Test IPv6 */
var_dump(expand_ip_address('2001:db8::abc'));

/* Test invalid */
var_dump(expand_ip_address('192:0:2:55'));
```

Which produce:

```
string(15) "192.000.002.055"
string(39) "2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0abc"
bool(false)
```

Comment: That is very nice! But what about for example `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1`?

Comment: Also, I think it does make sense to fill all of the IP sections (or however they are called) with 0000 if you are going to store them in the DB, but this perhaps not necessary anymore specifically for IPv4. How would I change your code to reflect only 1 '0' if there was no other digit? (You have a fairly complex `array_map(create_function(...))` for this section I think

Comment: If you don't want this for IPv4 then I would just to `return inet_ntop($addr_bin);`. But then you can't the operators like `<` and `>` anymore to search for address ranges. If every number has the same length then string comparison and numeric comparison give the same result (because all the dots are in the same place). Addresses like `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:192.168.0.1` are written as `0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:c0a8:0001` which is exactly the same address but in hex notation.

Comment: And yes: the array_map section is a bit complex. I probably shouldn't have tried to put it all on one line :-)