# How to convert from IPv6 to it's original IPv4 format? (inet_ntop(inet_pton('ip address'))

Tags: php, mysql, ip, codeigniter-2

So I convert the user's IP address [which is pretty much always in ipv4 format] using `inet_pton()` and then store in it mySQL using `binary(16)`, now when i extract that row/column, and use `inet_ntop` it creates a different format [and not the regular `192.123.1.0` etc...], such as `4c78:472a::`

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Just a fraction of IPv6 addresses can be directly mapped onto IPv4 addresses.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445582/change-ipv4-to-ipv6-string

Comment: According to the link ^ the ip address is actually that of IPv6 and not IPv4 since the numbers/letters are on the left side of the outputted string, which doesn't make sense to me.