# What's is better for a members database?

Tags: mysql, database

Hi and thanx for reading my post i am having a little trouble learning my  database in mysql.
Now i have it set up already but recently, but i had another person tell me my members table is slow and useless if i intend to have a lots of members!

I have looked it over a lot of times and did some google searches but i don't see anything wrong with it, maybe because i am new at it? can one of you sql experts look it over and tell me whats wrong with it please :)

```
--
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `userid` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` longtext,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gender` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ipaddress` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `joinedon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `acctype` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `acclevel` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `warnings` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `enabled` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `online` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `emailadd` (`emailadd`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--
```

It's going to be a site for faqs/tips for games, i do expect to get lots of members at one point later on but i thought i would ask to make sure it's all ok, thanx again peace.

Comment: What are you using the `ipaddress` field for?

Comment: I am using it several different things, one i am checking it against the one all ready stored in my database so if it don't match and they reach the 5 "try" limit on the login page it will auto ban them.

Answer (score 3):

Did the other person explain why they think it is slow and useless?

Here's a few things that I think could be improved:

`email` should be longer - off the top of my head, 320 should be long enough for most email addresses, but you might want to look that up.

If the `int(1)` fields are simple on/off fields, then they could be `tinyint(1)` or `bool` instead.

As @cularis points out, the `ipaddress` field might not be the appropriate type.  `INT UNSIGNED` is better than varchar for IPv4.  You can use [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) for conversion. See:

[Best Field Type for IP address?](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?21,49094,49094#msg-49094)
[How to store IPv6-compatible address in a relational database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420680/how-to-store-ipv6-compatible-address-in-a-relational-database)

As @Delan Azabani points out, your `password` field is too long for the value you are storing.  MD5 produces a 32 character string, so `varchar(32)` will be sufficient.  You could switch to the more secure SHA2, and use the MySQL ['SHA2()'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2) function.

Look into using the [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-storage-engine.html) database engine instead of MyISAM.  It offers foreign key constraints, row-level locking and transactions, amongst other things.  See [Should you move from MyISAM to Innodb ?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/01/12/should-you-move-from-myisam-to-innodb/).

Comment: Hi @Mike thanx for all the info i will check into those things and make it better, as for MD5 it's the only thing i could get working i don't know why but when ever i tried to set up the SHA2() it would never save the key to the password table? It kept coming out empty :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessarily slow, but I did notice that among all other text fields where you used `varchar`, you used `longtext` for the password field. This seems like you are going to store the password in the database -- **don't do this!**

Always take a fixed-length cryptographic hash (using, for example, SHA-1 or SHA-2) of the user's password, and put that into the database. That way, if your database server is compromised, the users' passwords are not exposed.

Comment: Hi yeah i am storing the password in my database but before it is put into it i have it MD5 encrypted is that what you mean? i tried to set up sha256 but i don't know how... So i just have it stored like this: $password = md5($password);

Comment: @Death: MD5 is not an encryption, it's a hash function. Basically, don't do this yourself, use a library like `bcrypt`, as you're likely to get it wrong and leave your passwords vulnerable to being discovered in the event that your database gets compromised.

Comment: Hi @Kerrek SB i am working on trying to add SHA2() to the join page today after i get home, i was told that MD5 was very secure and safe but now i am not so sure. I searched google and seen a MD5 Decrypt-er for it and i am scared to use it now.

Comment: You better be scared, and you really better not try to sell your homebrew solution to anyone! :-) I suggest first learning some fundamentals of cryptography, and then move on to fundamentals of authentication systems and how to handle password-based authentication.

Comment: Wait what @Kerrek SB what are you talking about (sell your homebrew solution)?? it's not for sale it is my personal site not for business just cheat codes.

Comment: @Death: Err... OK, maybe this conversation got away from me a little. Anyway, here's an interesting [article](http://www.openwall.com/articles/PHP-Users-Passwords) on managing passwords.

Comment: Oh a little XD @Kerrek SB thanx for the link i have been working hard on it and i must say the site is looking sexy just like me :) jk i got my join page all done and i was able to add the sha-2 it worked finally after 1 billion tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what @Delan said, I noted that;

1. `JoinedOn` column defined as `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. If you need to maintain only the date joined, you should not update the field when the records been updated.
2. `IPAddress` column is `VARCHAR(80)`. If you store IPv4 type IP addresses, this will be too lengthy.
3. Empty string (`''`) as `DEFAULT` for `NOT NULL` columns. Not good if intention is to have a value (other than `''`) on the field.
4. Empty string (`''`) as `DEFAULT` for `UNIQUE` Fields. This contradicts the contraints enforced if your intention is to have a Unique Value (other than `''`).

Comment: Hi @Kosala Nuwan i see that now thanx for pointing it out i am dumb some times, so i should just leave out the DEFAULT '' part?